# How to use atmoz/sftp?

Tags: bash, docker, containers, sftp

https://github.com/atmoz/sftp
I am trying to set this up for testing and I have attempted to follow the README with no luck. I need to log in with ssh keys but the directions but it keeps asking me for a password. I am not setting a password when the keys get generated.

```
/home/test/sftp_testing
$ ls
test1.txt  test2.txt  test3.txt  testing4.txt
$ ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -f ssh_host_ed25519_key < /dev/null
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f ssh_host_rsa_key < /dev/null
$ ls
ssh_host_ed25519_key  ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub  ssh_host_rsa_key  ssh_host_rsa_key.pub  test1.txt  test2.txt  test3.txt  testing4.txt
$ docker run \
>     -v /home/test/sftp_testing/ssh_host_ed25519_key:/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key \
>     -v /home/test/sftp_testing/ssh_host_rsa_key:/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key \
>     -v /home/test/sftp_testing/share:/home/foo/share \
>     -p 9000:22 -d atmoz/sftp \
>     foo::1001
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE        COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                   NAMES
7e10e9d5a864   atmoz/sftp   "/entrypoint foo::10…"   4 seconds ago   Up 3 seconds   0.0.0.0:9000->22/tcp, :::9000->22/tcp   priceless_edison
$ sftp -P 9000 -i /home/test/sftp_testing/ssh_host_rsa_key -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null foo@10.0.2.15
Warning: Permanently added '[10.0.2.15]:9000' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
foo@10.0.2.15`'s password:
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it looks like the instructions were not complete if you want to try to use a key. I was able to get it to work with the following:

```
docker run \
    -v /home/test/sftp_testing/ssh_host_ed25519_key:/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key \
    -v /home/test/sftp_testing/ssh_host_rsa_key:/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key \
    -v /home/test/sftp_testing/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub:/home/foo/.ssh/keys/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub:ro \
    -v /home/test/sftp_testing/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub:/home/foo/.ssh/keys/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub:ro \
    -v /home/test/sftp_testing/share:/home/foo/share \
    -p 9000:22 -d test_thing \
    foo::1001

sftp -P 9000 -i /home/testing/sftp_testing/ssh_host_ed25519_key -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null foo@10.0.2.15
```

Comment: Your 'test_thing' should be 'atmoz/sftp', correct?

Comment: You saved my day! I was wondering why the README.md is not updated after years

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue as well, in case any one else experiences the same. Similar to Cogito Ergo Sum I was able to get this working by mounting one of the generated public keys on the server and then passing the location of the private key file using the identity flag on connection i.e.

```
docker run -v /home/dev/share:/home/admin/share \
    -v /home/dev/resources/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub:/home/admin/.ssh/keys/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub:ro \
    --network host -d atmoz/sftp:debian admin::100:1001:share

sftp -i ssh_host_ed25519_key -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oUserKnownHostsFile=/home/dev/.ssh/known_hosts admin@localhost
```