# use atmoz-sftp in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, sftp

I look this question but it uses sha keys

[How to use atmoz/sftp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68459632/how-to-use-atmoz-sftp)

I have this in my docker-compose.yml

```
 sftp:
    image: atmoz/sftp:latest
    container_name: sftp
    ports:
      - "2000:22"
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/docker/volumes/sftp_conf/_data:/etc/sftp/  
    networks:
       red_interna:
          ipv4_address: 192.168.15.7
```

and for the user I have this simple users.conf file

```
test:1234:1000:100:mnt/Datos/SFTP/
```

When I start the docker, then it creates the folder path in home/test fine.

My problem is that now I connect with filezilla to my ip and port 2000 and seems like it connects

```
Estado: Conectando a 192.168.0.26:2000...
Respuesta:  fzSftp started, protocol_version=11
Comando:    open "test@192.168.0.26" 2000
Estado: Using username "test". 
Comando:    Pass: ****
Estado: Connected to 192.168.0.26
```

But I cannot see the folders and also get that connection is shutting down after 20 seconds of inactivity and then another message telling me that cannot connect to the server.

I just want to create an sftp with users and passwords.

Could you help me please?